# Using AtomicReference to access Object from another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a couple of ideas how to solve this problem, but I really would like to know the underlying reason for such a behavior. I have a class called ConferenceManager which is responsible for receiving callbacks from another thread(not main thread):

ConferenceManager(simplified):

```
public class ConferenceManager implements IConferenceManager {

private final AtomicReference<CallState> mCallStateHolder = new AtomicReference<CallState>(
            CallState.IDLE);

// excecuted on main thread
public boolean call(Context context, String peerId, String peerName, boolean isAudioCall) {
   // call the user, set the AtomicReference and start CallActivity
   // ...

   mCallStateHolder.compareAndSet(CallState.IDLE,
                CallState.PLACE_CALL);
   startCallActivity();
 }

// called from backgroundthread when call ends
public void onCallFinished() {
   // show toast that call has ended and set the AtomicReference
   // ...

   mCallStateHolder.compareAndSet(CallState.PLACE_CALL,
                CallState.IDLE);
}
```

}

CallState enum:

```
public enum CallState {
    PLACE_CALL, RECEIVE_CALL, CONFERENCE, IDLE, RECEIVE_CALL_FAKE, PLACE_CALL_FAKE
}
```

What CallActivity does in onResume() is checks whether mCallStateHolder is IDLE or not and if it is IDLE CallActivity will call finish(). The reason for this is that sometimes onCallFinished() might be executed very fast before onResume() is called, for instance if user is offline background thread will emmidietly call onCallFinished(). Since I use atomic reference I expect that if this happens the CallActivity will terminate in onResume().

So the problem is: despite using AtomicReference and excecuting onCallFinished() before onResume() the mCallStateHolder is still PLACE_CALL inside onResume(). So the main thread didn't see the changes? I used android studio debugger to check on it. The flow of the code using debugger is as follows:

1. MainThread - call() is called, call is started in background, and activity intent is sent
2. BackgroundThread - onCallFinished() is called and variable is set back to IDLE
3. MainThread - Activity onResume() is called and variable is PLACE_CALL

Comment: inter-thread comunication procedures must include calls to Object.wait() or Condition.await(). Atomic variables are not enough,

Comment: You do not check return value of `compareAndSet` method. Is this intentional?

Comment: @caco3 yeah, it is

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I guess I don't understand threads well enough. So even if using atomic operations I need to make sure that only one thread is executed at a time?

Comment: @Danil.B not sure why exactly this happens. To me it seems that you meant to write something like `if (!mCallStateHolder.compareAndSet(..,..)) return;` because as it currently written several threads are allowed to execute the same method (including the `onResume`). If that's still not true then there might be other issue, maybe involving something related with Android

Comment: @caco3 Well, the problem here is that when background thread sets the mCallStateHolder, main thread doesn't know about it sometimes, for instance when thread executed very quickly before main thread started new activity. And onResume is only executed by main thread there is no other way.

Comment: @caco3 Maybe I got it wrong, I just thought that atomic variable will make sure that variable changes are visible to other threads

Comment: @Danil.B can you please post relevant code of `CallActivity` and all code in `ConferenceManager` that accesses the `AtomicReference`?